Kivy Launcher - I put PIL in kivy directory but
env.:
device: Xiaomi POCO F3

python, hostpython: 3.11.7

I've created python 3 kivy launcher apk with Buildozer and it works fine.
Next, I tried to add PIL without mentioning in android.requirements in the spec file.
I added this codes in my py file:
from os import path
import sys
kivy_dir = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.append(kivy_dir)
from PIL import ImageGrab

and then the log says like this:
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/storage/emulated/0/kivy/PIL/_init_.py)
Do you have any ideas that doesn't require re-creating the apk?
I'll appreciate any of your helps!

If you have made changes to your py file, then you must re-create the apk.

Looks there’s no way to make it… Thank you anyway for your comment!

If you want to add a pure Python module not like PIL, you can do it.
This is an example to add kivy garden joystick:

Get joystick package from the repo and put them into a folder named 'joystick'.

Make a folder named 'packages' or a name you like in the kivy folder and put the joystick folder in it.

Add this code at the top of your main.py:


import os.path
import sys
packeges = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')), 'packages')
sys.path.append(packeges)

and then import the module like this:
from joystick import Joystick

All done! Enjoy it!
